# Dump linux password in clear text

Tags: passwords, linux, memory

Is it possible to dump a Linux password in clear text format?
In Windows it is possible to do so using "[Windows Credential Editor](http://www.ampliasecurity.com/research/wcefaq.html)".

Answer (score 6):

**Yes, it's possible.**

The WCE product you reference works by scraping passwords directly out of memory.  That method also works in Linux; a rootkit which has unfettered access to memory and can hook system calls can extract passwords from there - consider this example, which [can steal username and password pairs](https://isc.sans.edu/diary/SSHD+rootkit+in+the+wild/15229)

Both solutions are limited in that they

- can only capture passwords as they're used - someone has to log in to have their password compromised, it's not dumping the authentication store for everyone.
- require the OS to be hooked - let's just say *compromised* - at a deep level.

Comment: Is there any equivalent to WCE for Linux ?

Answer (score 3):

There is relativly persistant way to dump clear text password. The swap file.
Linux passwords are very often stored in swap in clear text.
To dump them you can use a tool like [swap_digger](https://github.com/sevagas/swap_digger)

This solution requires root access.

Comment: Do you have a source for "Linux passwords are very often stored in swap in clear text." ?

Comment: @user2313067 It's true. Whenever an application that does not lock memory handles a password, there is a chance that it will be written to the swap file which is, by default, unencrypted.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no, because the password file only contains non invertible hashes.

That being said is you have administrative priviledges on a machine, you have many ways to gather passwords:

- use a password cracker like JohnTheRipper - in some organizations, it is enough to get more than 50% or the total users passwords
- if the passwords are used unencrypted (plain POP, IMAP or FTP) a simple spy on the network interface will give them
- many services use PAM on Linux. It is easy to modify the pam_unix module to store the plain text password.

Of course this would be an internal security attack and an administrator should never do that without very special reasons.